# How to use a textarea to submit email from a html form without the name attribute

Tags: html

I have the following form:

```
<form action="mailto:example@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
     <textarea name="text" class="contact-email-text"></textarea>
     <div class="input-container">
       <input type="submit" value="SEND">
       <input type="reset" value="RESET">
     </div>
</form>
```

When I set the `name` attribute on the textarea this gets passed to my email client as text=actual input text. But when I do not set the name attribute the input text does not get passed to the email client at all.

How can I pass the text to the email client without the name attribute in front of it (I would like to avoid the prepending of the attribute to the email content)?

Comment: Not sure whether there is a standard that governs these things, it's possible every browser does what it wants there. What's the reasoning for not having a `name` attribute?

Comment: Because the name attribute gets prepended to the text in the email client

Comment: Don’t use `mailto:` (you don’t even know if I have an email client installed that can handle this) - use a proper server-side formmailer.

Comment: @CBroe This is exaclty what I am trying to avoid here - I am basically building a simple HTML landing page without any server-side funtionality. I guess an alternative would be to use serverlessforms or something similar, but I would like to find out if there is a html option first

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič — http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html — Assuming the user has an email client the browser can talk to is usually a bad idea.

Comment: You could try something evil like a `name` attribute with a space or `-`. Or one of those invisible Unicode spaces. (You'd have to test it across browsers and mail clients, though, this could be unreliable. And what the others say applies, too, of course...)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a different e-mail client?
This behavior could be from the one you're using.
Try Mozilla's Thunderbird and see if that is a standard or a specific behavior of your e-mail client, if so and you need this client, look for incompatibility issues.